# "org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection was evicted" spring 2.7.13 error

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, entity, relationship

I am trying to get an individual recipe with its respestive categories, using id. I am currently facing the following error, org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection was evicted. My understanding of ORM, Hibernate, and JDBC is still being developed.

I believe my mapping is off somewhere because creating a recipe throws an error if there is more than 1 category in the post request.

the database created looks like this:

recipe table

| id | title | Description | preptime | cooktime | servings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

categories table
| id | title | Description |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |

join table
| recipe_id | categories_id |
| -------- | -------- |

recipe model code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recipes")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Recipe {

    /* Model Recipe
     * The model is mapped to Model Category with a many-to-many relationship
     * has id as its unique identifier and mapper in the union table
     * It also has a one-to-many relationship with Model Ingredient
     * Its table will have 1 id mapped to many ingredientIds
     * */
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    public String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    public String description;

    @Column(name = "prep_time")
    private Integer prepTime;

    @Column(name = "cook_time")
    private Integer cookTime;

    @Column(name = "servings")
    private Integer servings;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
            })
    @JoinTable(name = "recipe_categories",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "category_id") })
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();
    
    //GETTERS AND SETTERS OMITTED FOR BREVITY

    public Recipe(){}

    public Recipe(String title, String description, Integer prepTime, Integer cookTime, Integer servings, Set<Category> categories){
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.prepTime = prepTime;
        this.cookTime = cookTime;
        this.servings = servings;
        this.categories = categories;
    }


    public void addCategory(Category category){
        this.categories.add(category);
        category.getRecipes().add(this);
    }

    public void removeCategory(Long categoryId){
        Category category = this.categories.stream().filter(c->c.getId() ==categoryId).findFirst().orElse(null);
        if (category != null) {
            this.categories.remove(category);
            category.getRecipes().remove(this);
        }

    }

    @JsonProperty("categories") // Map the JSON property to this field
    public void setCategoriesFromJson(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = new HashSet<>(categories);
    }

}
```

My categories Model:

```
public class Category {

    /* Model Category
     * The model is mapped to Model Recipes with a many-to-many relationship
     * has id as its unique identifier and mapper in the union table
     * */

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    public String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    public String description;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
            },
            mappedBy = "categories")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Recipe> recipes = new HashSet<>();

    public Category(){}
    
    //GETTERS AND SETTERS EXCLUDED FOR BREVITY
}
```

My repositories extend JPArepository and includes the following methods:

```
    recipeRepo*
    List<Recipe> findRecipesByCategoriesId(Long categoryId);

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "categories")
    List<Recipe> findAll();
    
    categoryRepo*
    List<Category> findCategoryByRecipesId(Long recipeId);
```

And lastly my recipe controller looks like this:

```
  @PostMapping("/create-recipe")
  public ResponseEntity<Recipe> createRecipe(@RequestBody Recipe recipe) {
        // Fetch categories from the database and set them in the recipe
        Set<Category> fetchedCategories = new HashSet<>();
        for (Category category : recipe.getCategories()) {
            fetchedCategories.add(categoryRepository.findById(category.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Category not found")));
        }
        recipe.setCategories(fetchedCategories);

        // Perform any necessary validation and save the recipe to the database
        recipeRepository.save(recipe);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(recipe, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

@GetMapping("/recipe/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Recipe> getRecipeById(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        Optional<Recipe> recipe = recipeRepository.findById(id);
        if(recipe.isPresent()){

            return ResponseEntity.ok(recipe.get());
        }else{
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }
```

Initially i was getting 500 internal server error, then i found a solution that implemented @EntityGraph to fetch categories along with recipes,

and adding @jsonproperty in the recipe model along with the method:

```
@JsonProperty("categories") // Map the JSON property to this field
    public void setCategoriesFromJson(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = new HashSet<>(categories);
    }
```

That's when I started getting this error.